# Cloudboost: Setting up a website

Tags: javascript, sockets, cloudboost

I'm trying to create a social site using cloudboost but I keep getting this error:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://realtime.cloudboost.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=PUsvsrEipNM0t6BGAALX' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

`socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 POST https://realtime.cloudboost.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LE0PghP&sid=PUsvsrEipNM0t6BGAALX 400 (Bad Request)`

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CB</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cloudboost.io/js-sdk/cloudboost.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        CB.CloudApp.init('xxx', 'xxx');     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'xxx' is of course replaced with my app id and client key. I've tried storing someting into the database but nothing works just keeps showing that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're working on it to fix it. You should be able to use CloudBoost normally though. Expect this to be fixed in 2 more days.